# Dates along x-axis of quadmesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to use matplotlib and `Axes.pcolormesh` to create a plot.  My problem is that I want to have dates along the x-axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
qmesh = ax.pcolormesh(times,mlt,data.T)
fig.colorbar(qmesh,ax=ax)
```

in this code, `times` is a (1D) numpy array created using `matplotlib.dates.date2num`.  This creates a perfectly reasonable plot except that the x-axis is labeled with values on the order of `1e5` instead of dates/times in the format `'%H:%M'`.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the answer you already found, you can do `ax.xaxis_date()`, which is effectively equivalent.

As a quick example (which also uses `fig.autofmt_xdate()` to rotate the x-labels):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

# Generate some data
x = mdates.drange(dt.datetime(2012, 01, 01), dt.datetime(2013, 01, 01),
                  dt.timedelta(weeks=2))
y = np.linspace(1, 10, 20)
data = np.random.random((y.size, x.size))

# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
qmesh = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, data)
fig.colorbar(qmesh,ax=ax)
ax.axis('tight')

# Set up as dates
ax.xaxis_date()
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joe, I can always count on you for more valuable insight into how matplotlib works.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I needed a:

```
import matplotlib.dates as dates
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

in there.

Comment: As always, feel free to post a better answer.